Matplotlib Themes Not Applying
I have created a GUI with customtkinter to plot charts. One of the options I have is a drop down menu of different themes. When I run the script in PyCharm, the selected theme in the drop down option box is applied. When I run the script through the terminal or an executable I have made, the themes do not get applied.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled matplotlib in my main system interpreter. I have imported matplotlib as plt and am using plt.style.use() in my script.
When run from the terminal (not an ide), I tried to set the theme in a drop down option box, and expected said theme to be applied but it did not work.
def generate_plot():
x = df[drp_sel_plt_x.get()]
x = list(set(x))

x_start = int(ent_x_lbl_start.get())
y_start = float(ent_y_lbl_start.get())

x_end = int(ent_x_lbl_end.get())
y_end = float(ent_y_lbl_end.get())

y_plt_rot = int(ent_plt_rot.get())
x_inc = int(ent_x_inc_end.get())
y_inc = float(ent_y_inc.get())

for f in range(len(x)):
    x[f] = float(x[f])
    x[f] = round(x[f])
y = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    value = x[i]
    y_temp = df[df[drp_sel_plt_x.get()] == value][drp_sel_plt_y.get()]
    y_temp = y_temp.mean()
    y.append(y_temp)
    
y_ticks_min = min(y)
y_ticks_max = max(y)
y_ticks = np.arange(y_ticks_min, y_ticks_max, 10)

x_lbl = ent_x_lbl.get()
y_lbl = ent_y_lbl.get()
title = ent_tit_lbl.get()

style = drp_plt_sty.get()
plt.style.use(style)
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle=drp_line_plt_x.get(), marker=drp_mrkr_plt_x.get())
plt.xticks(x, rotation=y_plt_rot, )
plt.yticks(y_ticks)
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(x)  # Set the tick labels
ax = plt.gca()
# Set x-axis major ticks with custom increments
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(x_inc))
# Set y-axis major ticks with custom increments
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(y_inc))
plt.xlabel(x_lbl)
plt.ylabel(y_lbl)
plt.title(title)
plt.xlim(x_start, x_end)
plt.ylim(y_start, y_end)
plt.show()


Added the functions code...

Thanks for the PHD level English lesson, that's what I needed.

One cannot change the style of an existing figure with plt.style.use, see e.g. How can I change the style of a Matplotlib plot, after it is created?.
If you would define a new figure (e.g. plt.figure() at the start of generate_plot()) this approach would work. But it might break your intended interaction.
